# Static import and class file generation

Tags: java

If we use static import for a class, will the compiler generate a class file for statically imported class when compiling the actual class?

Ex:

```
import static com.x.y.util.B.getIds();

public class A {
 ...
}
```

When compiler compiles class `A`, will it generate class files for `B` as well?

Comment: This import doesn't look good. Also, if class `B` is inside `A`, there's no need to import it. Class files are generated for all classes, regardless of the fact if they're static or not, declared or anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

No, import statement does not cause compiler to generate anything. Think about it: how can compiler generate class if it does not have a source code? Compiler by definition translate source code into executable code (or byte code in case of java).

BTW the syntax of static import in your example is not correct. You should not use `()` in static import:

`import static com.x.y.util.B.getIds;`

Comment: I am not sure whether my question was clear, but is not about generating class file without source code, source code is there, but should we compile both the classes A and B separately and then execute A or is it enough if we compile A. Just like anonymous inner class, compiler generates $1.class. The reason why I got this doubt is in one of our application in dev environment without a statically imported class being there in the server, it works fine, but in local environment it is not working, I had to include that class also into the build.
Yes, thanks for correcting the syntax :)

Comment: In this case the answer is yes, import statement as any other reference causes dependent classes to be compiled. But typically you do not have to care about this: any build system does not for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use some type in class using key word import or just by full name to it. You must assure that during compilation time, compiler has that both classes in build path.

The static import allow you to access static members of imported class. Nothing more.

```
class Bar {

 public static int getID() {
    return -1;
 }

}
```

And for static import

```
import static Bar.getID;

class Foo {

   private void foo() {
    int id = getID(); //instead of Bar.getID();
   }

}
```

[Read more on Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)